# Create multiple XML files from an Access DB query

Tags: xml, ms-access, xml-parsing, vba

I'd like to be able to use VBA or a macro (or any other method for that matter) to export a query or report in an Access database into multiple XML files.  The query would look something like below.  My requirement is to export an individual XML file for each location.  So for example, 236 would have it's own file, 1411 would have it's own, etc. and each file would contain only those lines of data for that location.

[image]

I'm able to do this when exporting to Excel, but when I switch to XML using ExportXML it exports the files fine and names each file by location as I'd like (236.xml, 1411.xml, etc.) but each file has all the data in it (isn't filtered to just that location).  My VBA:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT [Location] FROM [MyTable] ORDER BY [Location];", dbOpenSnapshot)

Do While Not rst.EOF
strRptFilter = "[Location] = " & rst![Location]
Debug.Print "strRptFilter"
ExportXML acExportTable, "MyTable", "FolderLocation" & "\" & rst![Location] & ".xml"
DoEvents
rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

Is this possible to do?  Am I going about it all wrong?  Is there a better method or solution to accomplish what I need?  I've thought about maybe trying to create a looping query which re runs the query, changing the filter criteria, and exporting by location or possibly exporting the entire file to XML and finding some other way to parse the file.  I'm open to any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your `strRptFilter` string as the *WhereCondition* option of the [Application.ExportXML Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193212.aspx).

```vb
Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
    DataSource:="MyTable", _
    DataTarget:="FolderLocation" & "\" & rst![Location] & ".xml", _
    WhereCondition:=strRptFilter
```